# How to change WebStorm folding style in React.js？

Tags: reactjs, webstorm

I want the fold style to be like this，showing the class name, tag attribute:

[image]

But when I coding in React.js, fold style does not show class name. How can I set it up?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be configured; please follow [WEB-41780](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-41780) for updates